SQL Scalar Result changes by looping through it?
I'm building a simple project management web-app that is supposed to display task cards in the respective row of the responsible user. I'm working with Flask and SQLAlchemy.
For this part I need both the Scalar Result of all tasks in the database as well as a set of all different users. After I looped through the Scalar Result, it appears to be empty. I made a test and looped through it twice, depending which loop I did first the other one's empty. Can anyone explain this to me please?
tasks = db.session.execute(db.select(Task)).scalars()
user_ids = set([task.user_id for task in tasks])
print([task.title for task in tasks])
print(user_ids)

result:
[]
{1}


tasks = db.session.execute(db.select(Task)).scalars()
print([task.title for task in tasks])
user_ids = set([task.user_id for task in tasks])
print(user_ids)

['ghjklh', 'fjdlf']
set()


It's an iterator, you can only loop over it once.  Do tasks = tasks.all()  to convert it to a list.
